# Accountability for Users Hiding/Deleting Answers?

Tags: support, questions

I have experienced multiple cases of answers and/or comments on a question being removed without any indication of the removal, and often before I am able to read the entire content posted.  See:

[The Question of Interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26415715/sim-usim-do-any-carriers-allow-3rd-party-applet-install/30496169#30496169)

For example, this AM I received an email indicating a new answer to my question, and the preview text seemed promising -- but upon clickthrough, the answer was absent!  This is the first time I've had this sort of experience with a StackExchange Q+A site, and am not sure if it is unique to SO, or if there is some way I can actually obtain the information in the answers to my question before some other user deletes it.

Comment: That answer was deleted by a moderator. It's a link-only answer that may even be spam.

Comment: It was also the same link that was plagiarized from in an earlier deleted answer that the OP saw.

Comment: @Andy: you are getting confused by posts that were deleted much earlier; those two answers were from October 2014.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out your off-topic question to us!  Looks like a honeypot for justaskgemalto.com spam.

Comment: @Will of course, any explanation for that 'off-topic' indicator would be nice; but I assume you've got some reason why my question would be OT but these similar questions would not:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377877/sim-application-toolkit-development

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769645/sim-application-toolkit-creation

Comment: @jjmilburn All three questions are off topic.

Comment: @Servy I understood this question to fall under
 "software tools commonly used by programmers" and thought that it might have "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development".  I suppose tools for USIM development in a 3rd party context might be off-topic if the 'commonly used' part was missing, though.

Comment: @jjmilburn A request for a tool is very different than a question *about* a tool.  The former is off topic, the latter is on topic.

Comment: Understood, got it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When an answer is deleted it is *soft* deleted; users with 10k or more reputation as well as moderators can still see the answer. As such a lot of users can see if a post was deleted and why.

In this case the post was deleted from the Low Quality review queue, undeleted by the author, then deleted again by a moderator.

Comment: Do mods get notified when a user undeletes a post that was review deleted?

Comment: @Mysticial: an automatic flag is raised, yes.

Comment: Ah. I figured as such since (SO) mods probably aren't running around looking for stuff like this unless the system tells them to. :)

Comment: @martijnpieters thanks, that is helpful -- I may not understand the philosophy behind 'why would the question author never be notified in this entire process', but oh well.

Comment: @Mysticial - We requested something like this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228479/135615 because some of these undeleted non-answers were slipping through. The flags catch almost all of them now.